# Prevent git submodules from reverting to a previous commit when doing a recursive pull

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repo which contains several submodules. It's usually convenient to do a `git pull --recurse-submodules` on the main repo, I tend to even have it activated permanently with `git config submodule.recurse true`.

The issue is that sometimes a submodule has new commits and the main module hasn't been updated to contain the new submodule commit yet. In this case a `git pull` reverts the submodule to a previous commit in a headless state.

I would like to prevent git from reverting submodules to a previous commit. That is, if the submodule commit contained in the main repo is behind what is currently checked out in a submodule, then a `git pull` / `git pull --recurse-submodules` should not change what's checked out in the submodule. How can I set this up?

Comment: "I would like to prevent git from reverting submodules to a previous commit." Then don't use submodules. The whole idea behind submodules is that the commit is stored in the parent repository so you always get a known state. If that's not the behavior you want, then submodules aren't the correct solution.